# How to get downloaded content data from the root element? Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

After hours of googling, I haven't succeeded with finding a solution.

I want to add a share functionality into an article. Something like a wordpress shortcode.  So, There is content with  < feature > Feature content < /feature > inside.  The article can have multiple features.

Now, I understand that there must be a root element. And this is where the problem rises.  When I put the article inside < blog-app >  < /blog-app >  component, the content is  overwritten with the component template.

I know there is < ng-content >, but this only works inside the root component.

I want to have the article content loaded with the page to let the search engines see the content even when no javascript is launched. So, I don't want to load the content with REST API.

How would you deal with it?  How should I read the original article and then how to put it inside the angular root element?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a little hack, but it might not work in all situations.

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'blog-app',
  template: document.getElementsByTagName('blog-app')[0].innerHTML

})

export class BlogAppComponent {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you put an `<ng-content></ng-content>` tag in the component's template? It should preserve - aka "project" - the original content, no?

BEFORE Angular compilation (this is the raw `index.html` returned by the server):

```
<body>
  <my-app>
    <p>Some article content</p>
  </my-app>
</body>
```

AFTER Angular compilation (this is the page AFTER it has been compiled by Angular in the client's browser; this part wouldn't be executed if JavaScript was disabled in the client's browser):

```
<body>
  <my-app>

    <!-- Some elements coming from the component's template, e.g. nav... -->

    <!-- The NG-CONTENT tag should be replaced by the original content: -->
    <p>Some article content</p>

    <!-- More elements coming from the component's template, e.g. footer... -->

  </my-app>
</body>
```

The component for `my-app` would then look something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <!-- navbar elements -->

    <ng-content></ng-content>

    <!-- footer elements -->
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {}
```

Comment: I tried this in several variations and it doesn't work. Based on some articles I read, it is even not supposed to work.  ng-content only works with  inner components.

Comment: Well then, why not add an intermediary component just to get it to work? e.g. `<my-app><inner-comp><p>YOUR CONTENT</p></inner-comp></my-app>`

Comment: I tried this as well, but it doesn't solve the problem.  It would work only if

<inner-comp><p>YOUR CONTENT</p></inner-comp>

was inside my-app  template.  Which is not my case.  It seems that angular2 cannot do this yet and that makes it almost useless for non-SPA projects.